# Swift on OS X: How to access the current CGContext for drawing in -[NSView drawRect:]

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, swift, cgcontext

## Setup:

Xcode 6.1
OS X 10.9.5
**Swift Mac** Document-based Application target

## Question:

I am using **Swift** to make a Cocoa **Mac** app (*NOT iOS*!). I have a custom `NSView` subclass. I'd like to override `-drawRect:`, and access the current `CGContext` to do some drawing using the CoreGraphics APIs.

However, I can't seem to access the current `CGContext` in Swift (something I've done hundreds of times in ObjC). Here's my code:

```
import Cocoa

class Canvas: NSView {
    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: CGRect) {
        if let ctx: CGContext! = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext {
            // do drawing
        }
    }
}
```

When I run, I get an immediate crash on the first line of my `drawRect` implementation:

```
-[NSWindowGraphicsContext CGContext]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60800005e840
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I fetch the current `CGContext` for drawing in Swift?

## NOTE:

I definitely want to use the CoreGraphics API. Unless using the CoreGraphics API in Swift is entirely impossible, please do not respond with suggestions on how to use AppKit drawing APIs instead (I don't care if they are easier). I want to know how to use CoreGraphics from Swift on OS X.

Comment: OP here. Immediately after posting this question I realized that `-[NSGraphicsContext CGContext]` is a 10.10 API. And as I stated, I am developing on 10.9 (even though my target is using the 10.10 Base SDK). So, that's the problem. This question is dumb, basically. This is literally the first line of Swift code I've written, so I'm still groping around, and I had just assumed I was doing something wrong syntactically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, `CGContext` is only available in 10.10+. There’s also `graphicsPort`, but it has type `UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>` (and presumably must be wrangled somewhat to recover a viable `CGContext`), and it’s deprecated in 10.10.

If that doesn’t seem viable, you could create a bitmap context using `CGBitmapContextCreate` and draw into that; then you can retrieve an image from it and draw that to see the results.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. It looks I really need to move to developing on 10.10 immediately to make things easier for myself. Gonna do that now.

Answer (score 27):

**Example**

*Swift 4+*

```swift
class CustomView: NSView {

    private var currentContext : CGContext? {
        get {
            if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
                return NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext
            } else if let contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.current?.graphicsPort {
                return Unmanaged.fromOpaque(contextPointer).takeUnretainedValue()
            }

            return nil
        }
    }

    private func saveGState(drawStuff: (CGContext) -> ()) -> () {
        if let context = self.currentContext {
            context.saveGState ()
            drawStuff(context)
            context.restoreGState ()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)

        saveGState { ctx in
            // Drawing code here.
        }
    }
}
```

*Swift 3*

```swift
class CustomView: NSView {

    private var currentContext : CGContext? {
        get {
            if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
                return NSGraphicsContext.current?.CGContext
            } else if let contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.graphicsPort {
                let context: CGContextRef = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(contextPointer)).takeUnretainedValue()
                return context
            }
            
            return nil
        }
    }

    private func saveGState(drawStuff: (ctx:CGContextRef) -> ()) -> () {
        if let context = self.currentContext {
            CGContextSaveGState (context)
            drawStuff(ctx: context)
            CGContextRestoreGState (context)
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        
        saveGState { ctx in
            // Drawing code here.
        }
    }
}
```

*Swift 2*

```swift
class CustomView: NSView {

    private var currentContext : CGContext? {
        get {
            if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
                return NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.CGContext
            } else if let contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.currentContext()?.graphicsPort {
                let context: CGContextRef = Unmanaged.fromOpaque(COpaquePointer(contextPointer)).takeUnretainedValue()
                return context
            }
            
            return nil
        }
    }

    private func saveGState(drawStuff: (ctx:CGContextRef) -> ()) -> () {
        if let context = self.currentContext {
            CGContextSaveGState (context)
            drawStuff(ctx: context)
            CGContextRestoreGState (context)
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
        
        saveGState { ctx in
            // Drawing code here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very elegant!
However, it only works in Swift 2?

Comment: Use `let ctx = NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext` in Swift 3+.

Answer (score 2):

**Eporediese**s answer can be updated to

**Swift 4**

```
private var currentContext : CGContext? {
    get {
        if #available(OSX 10.10, *) {
            return NSGraphicsContext.current?.cgContext
        } else if let contextPointer = NSGraphicsContext.current?.graphicsPort {
            return Unmanaged.fromOpaque(contextPointer).takeUnretainedValue()
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```